# Im having an issue with the append function in scheme

Tags: scheme

so i have been working on this simple transposition prog could some one tell me why my append isnt working?

```
(define stuff
  (lambda (x y)
      (if (null? y) 0)
      (if (not (null? (car y))) (stuff (append x (list (map car y))) (map cdr y)))
  ))

(define x '()) 
(define y '(( 1 2 3 4 )( 4 5 6 7 )( 7 8 9 0 )))
(stuff x y)
```

It appears to work if you look at the debug statements

Comment: What are you trying to do? Something like: `(map list '(1 2 3 4) '(4 5 6 7) '(7 8 9 0))` ?

Comment: And "if you look at the debug statements" is not very helpful. I see no debug statements ...

Answer (score 2):

You can't write two `if` expressions in a row like you are doing; because `if` is an expression, it will evaluate the first one (`(if (null? y) 0)`), discard the answer (since you are not using it anywhere), and then run the second one (which will return an undefined value if `(car y)` is empty).  Also, what will happen if `y` is not empty but its first element is empty?  That case is not handled.  Typically, in Scheme, you use `cond` to replace what would be an if-elseif-else chain in other languages.  What specifically is failing otherwise?  I think your code will work or nearly work if you fix the `if` problem and handle the other case I mentioned.

Comment: i get the same error (define stuff
  (lambda (x y)
    
      (cond
      ((not (null? (car y))) (stuff (append x (list (map car y))) (map cdr y)))
      
  )))

Comment: You also need to handle the `(null? y)` and `(null? (car y))` cases in your `cond` expression.